# Changing styles depends on state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, styled-components

I am trying to hide a component when the user had signed in already

```
const Container = styled.div`
  display: ${(props) => props.loggedIn ? 'none' : 'block'};
`

this.state {
  loggedIn: false
}

getUrl = () => {

  //conditions to determine if user already loggedIn {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      loggedIn: !prevState.loggedIn,
   }));

}

componentDidMount() {
  this.getUrl()
}

render() {
return (
  <SomeComponent>
   <Row>
      <Col>
        <Navbar> Navbar </Navbar>
      </Col>
      <Col>
        <Container>
          <SomeStyles>
            //somestyles
          </SomeStyles>
          <Menu>
            //MenuList
          </Menu>
        </Container>
      </Col>
    <Row>
  </SomeComponent>
);
}
}
```

The setState is working already. But the problem is when I'm trying to pass it in Styled Components, It only get the default value of the "loggedIn" state which is false. So it always end up getting the 'block' value for the display.

Comment: can you edit question with your rendering logic?

Comment: `getUrl = () => {

  //conditions to determine if user already loggedIn {
  this.setState({ loggedIn: !this.state.loggedIn })

}`

Comment: @MSoheb I dont have a problem with that because it's already working. The only problem is the passing of the props to styled components because it only gets the default value

Comment: In that case you have to show how you are trying to render the component

Comment: Please make a producible example, where do you use the Container?

Comment: @DennisVash I've edited it already. Sorry

Comment: Please show the whole component, not a snippet, [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @cmll I do not see that you are passing props to your Container. That's why you are not able to see any changes. [Check this](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/styled-components-essentials-in-three-steps-a61fb9372ded)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `loggedIn` property to `Container`:

```
// Styled Container
const Container = styled.div`
  display: ${(props) => props.loggedIn ? 'none' : 'block'};
`

// Components tree
<SomeComponent>
  <Row>
    <Col>
      <Navbar> Navbar </Navbar>
    </Col>
    <Col>
      <Container loggedIn={this.state.loggedIn}>
        <SomeStyles/>
        <Menu/>
      </Container>
    </Col>
  </Row>
</SomeComponent>
```

Comment: It worked! I forgot to pass the loggedIn property. Thank you sir!

Comment: You have one more option to achieve the result without styled components. 
You can use conditional rendering instead of using css display property.
````
{props.loggedIn && <Container loggedIn={this.state.loggedIn}>
        <SomeStyles/>
        <Menu/>
      </Container>
}
````

Comment: Note that you lose the state of the component because you unmounting it, it depends on the use case.

Answer (score 0):

I think  you should use state instead of props in your style, as props is readonly and your changes is only effect the state